# jQuery validation plugin not validating a select box

Tags: jquery, validation, select, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting jquery.validation.js to validate a select box. It is working on the text inputs, but it does not display an error message for the select. If I fulfill validation on the text inputs, it submits. Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

```
<form name="consumerRegistration" id="consumerRegistration" action="" method="post">
    <label for="name" class="baseline-10">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" placeholder="John Doe" min-length="2"/>
    <label for="email" class="baseline-10">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" placeholder="jdoe@yahoo.com"/>
    <label for="company" class="baseline-10">Company</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="ie. Yahoo"/>
    <select name="country" id="country" class="required" required="required">
        <option selected="" val="" disabled="disabled">Country</option>
        <option val="United States">United States</option>
        <option val="Canada">Canada</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:document.void(1);" title="Register" class="cta"><span>Register</span></a>
```

```
(function($){
if($('form#consumerRegistration').length){
    $('input').placeholder();
    $('form#consumerRegistration').find('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('form#consumerRegistration').valid()){
            $('form#consumerRegistration').submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

If I've missed a solution somewhere else in the site, I swear I've looked thouroughly. :)

The plugin is from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ .

Comment: Well, I can't tell what's wrong without seeing the code from jquery.validation.js. So maybe you should add that to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added a link to the plugin homepage, but I didn't include the code here because it seemed like 1100 lines might be overkill.

Comment: thanks for the cleanup Glenn ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your problem is that you're not really using jquery validate correctly.  What you need to do is more like this:

First, setup the validation on document.ready, if you don't do this, it doesn't validate the form any other way:

```
$('form#consumerRegistration').validate(...//options here
```

Next, create a click event for your `a` elements that just submits the form (validate will then do its thing)

```
$('form#consumerRegistration').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    $('form#consumerRegistration').submit();
});
```

Finally, the reason your select isn't being dealt with correctly is that you haven't specified its attributes correctly.  Simply, `val` is not the right attribute for your options, `value` is.  So just change that in all the options:

```
    <option selected="" value="" disabled="disabled">Country</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
```

Here it is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/TTpSB/

Comment: I'm smacking myself right now, I can't beleive I effed with this so long and didn't catch the mis named attribute. Thanks for figuring this out, I'll give the other fixes a try as well.

Comment: ^5. I'm an idiot for the "val" issue, but I'm glad it prevented validation, cause it works with the correct attribute, but I'd never have realized I was mis-implementing the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Validation Plugin requires the first option of select to be blank to validate them. 
Ex: your select box should look like Following :

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="required">
        <option></option>
        <option val="United States">United States</option>
        <option val="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```